# ng-form and ng-submit in a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-form

I have been trying to get a nested form to validate properly and then call a function on my controller when the submit button is clicked. I have tried remove all buttons except the submit button and it does not work. The only thing that I have been able to get to work is Ng-click on the button but I need validation and this method did not allow validation to fire.

Here is the method in the Controller and HTML which works if called via a ng-click

```js
 saveRow(row: ControlDetailDTO) {
            row.FiscalYearValues.forEach(value => {
                value.ActualValue = value.PreviousYear + value.DeltaValue;
            });
            
            this.controlsDataContext.saveDetail(row).then((results) => {

                console.log(results);
                row.editMode = false;

            }).catch((err) => {
                    this.$scope.error = err.data.ExceptionMessage;
                });
        }
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-responsive">

                <tr ng-repeat-start="control in newControl.ControlDetails" class="headerLightBlue" ng-show="$first" ng-form="edit">
                    <th colspan="2">Category</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>{{control.FiscalYearValues[0].FiscalYear.FiscalYearName }}</th>
                    <th>{{control.FiscalYearValues[1].FiscalYear.FiscalYearName }}</th>
                    <th>{{control.FiscalYearValues[2].FiscalYear.FiscalYearName }}</th>
                    <th>{{control.FiscalYearValues[3].FiscalYear.FiscalYearName }}</th>
                    <th>{{control.FiscalYearValues[4].FiscalYear.FiscalYearName }}</th>
                    <th>{{control.FiscalYearValues[5].FiscalYear.FiscalYearName }}</th>
                    <th></th>
                <tr>
                    <ng-form name="edit" ng-submit="saveRow(control)" novalidate>
                        <td ng-show="control.editMode" colspan="2"><select name="Category" class="form-control" id="Category" required ng-model="control.Category" ng-options="category.CategoryName for category in categories track by category.Id"><option value="">Select Appropriation</option></select></td>
                        <td ng-show="!control.editMode" colspan="2">{{control.Category.CategoryName}}</td>

                        <td ng-show="!control.editMode">{{control.Description}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="!control.editMode" ng-style="common.setColorCurrency(control.FiscalYearValues[0].DeltaValue)">{{control.FiscalYearValues[0].DeltaValue | inThousands | currency : $ : 0}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="!control.editMode" ng-style="common.setColorCurrency(control.FiscalYearValues[1].DeltaValue)">{{control.FiscalYearValues[1].DeltaValue | inThousands | currency : $ : 0}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="!control.editMode" ng-style="common.setColorCurrency(control.FiscalYearValues[2].DeltaValue)">{{control.FiscalYearValues[2].DeltaValue | inThousands | currency : $ : 0}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="!control.editMode" ng-style="common.setColorCurrency(control.FiscalYearValues[3].DeltaValue)">{{control.FiscalYearValues[3].DeltaValue | inThousands | currency : $ : 0}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="!control.editMode" ng-style="common.setColorCurrency(control.FiscalYearValues[4].DeltaValue)">{{control.FiscalYearValues[4].DeltaValue | inThousands | currency : $ : 0}}</td>
                        <td ng-show="!control.editMode" ng-style="common.setColorCurrency(control.FiscalYearValues[5].DeltaValue)">{{control.FiscalYearValues[5].DeltaValue | inThousands | currency : $ : 0}}</td>

                        <td ng-show="control.editMode"><input name="Description" class="form-control input-md" id="Description" required="" type="text" placeholder="" ng-model="control.Description"></td>
                        <td ng-show="control.editMode" ng-style="common.setColorCurrency(control.FiscalYearValues[0].DeltaValue)"><input name="FY0" class="form-control input-md" id="FY0" required="" type="number" placeholder="" required ng-model="control.FiscalYearValues[0].DeltaValue"></td>
                        <td ng-show="control.editMode" ng-style="common.setColorCurrency(control.FiscalYearValues[1].DeltaValue)"><input name="FY1" class="form-control input-md" id="FY1" required="" type="number" placeholder="" required ng-model="control.FiscalYearValues[1].DeltaValue"></td>
                        <td ng-show="control.editMode" ng-style="common.setColorCurrency(control.FiscalYearValues[2].DeltaValue)"><input name="FY2" class="form-control input-md" id="FY2" required="" type="number" placeholder="" required ng-model="control.FiscalYearValues[2].DeltaValue"></td>
                        <td ng-show="control.editMode" ng-style="common.setColorCurrency(control.FiscalYearValues[3].DeltaValue)"><input name="FY3" class="form-control input-md" id="FY3" required="" type="number" placeholder="" required ng-model="control.FiscalYearValues[3].DeltaValue"></td>
                        <td ng-show="control.editMode" ng-style="common.setColorCurrency(control.FiscalYearValues[4].DeltaValue)"><input name="FY4" class="form-control input-md" id="FY4" required="" type="number" placeholder="" required ng-model="control.FiscalYearValues[4].DeltaValue"></td>
                        <td ng-show="control.editMode" ng-style="common.setColorCurrency(control.FiscalYearValues[5].DeltaValue)"><input name="FY5" class="form-control input-md" id="FY5" required="" type="number" placeholder="" required ng-model="control.FiscalYearValues[5].DeltaValue"></td>


                        <td ng-show="!control.editMode"><button name="button3id" ng-show="control.isEditable && $last" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="editRow(control)" id="button3id" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover="Edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button></td>
                        <td ng-show="control.editMode" width="100px"><button name="button3id" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="cancelEdit(control)" id="button3id" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover="Cancel Changes"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></button>&nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="saveRow" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover="Save Changes"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button></td>


                    </ng-form>

                </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: You should give your forms different names. You can do this by including $index in the form name.

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu I just tried that and it still did not solve the firing issue. It will not call the function or validate.

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat creates child scopes for each repeated item, and my guess is that there's a scope visibility issue which is preventing the validation from working.

Consider using ng-form directive:

http://www.benlesh.com/2013/03/angular-js-validating-form-elements-in.html

http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/forms/nestedforms/

This is a handy article that can help you:

http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/building-dynamic-angular-forms-with-ngrepeat-and-ngform

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried working with the various different ways from your links but was to no help. I think my issue lies in the way that the ng-repeat and ng-forms are used. Essentially this code snippet allows for a custom editable inline form. There are at times tons of fields. I'm not sure if the naming is what is causing the issues or if this is not something angular allows.